# Unable to resolve any beans for Type: xxx; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have a LoginProvider interface:

```
public interface LoginProvider {
    boolean login(String username, String password);
}
```

And 2 different implementations:

```
public class LoginProvider1Impl implements LoginProvider {
    @Override
    public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        ...
    }
}

public class LoginProvider2Impl implements LoginProvider {
    @Override
    public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then a producer annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR})
    public @interface LoginProviderProducer {
}
```

An annotation to specify the Login Provider implementation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface LoginProviderType {
    LoginProviderName value();

    public enum LoginProviderName {

        PROVIDER1(LoginProvider1Impl.class),
        PROVIDER2(LoginProvider2Impl.class);

        private Class<? extends LoginProvider> loginProviderType;

        private LoginProviderName(Class<? extends LoginProvider> loginProviderType) {
            this.loginProviderType = loginProviderType;
        }

        public Class<? extends LoginProvider> getLoginProviderType() {
            return loginProviderType;
        }
    }
}
```

And a factory:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoginProviderFactory {

    @Produces
    @LoginProviderProducer
    public LoginProvider createLoginProvider(@Any Instance<LoginProvider> instance, InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Annotated annotated = injectionPoint.getAnnotated();
        LoginProviderType loginProviderTypeAnnotation = annotated.getAnnotation(LoginProviderType.class);
        Class<? extends LoginProvider> loginProviderType = loginProviderTypeAnnotation.value().getLoginProviderType();
        return instance.select(loginProviderType).get();
    }
}
```

Finally I have a helper in which the login providers are injected:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoginProviderHelperImpl implements LoginProviderHelper {

    @Inject
    @LoginProviderProducer
    @LoginProviderType(LoginProviderName.PROVIDER1)
    private LoginProvider provider1;

    @Inject
    @LoginProviderProducer
    @LoginProviderType(LoginProviderName.PROVIDER2)
    private LoginProvider provider2;

    ...
}
```

I get this error when the helper is used:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException:
WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type:
class com.xxx.LoginProvider1Impl; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure LoginProvider1Impl is part of your deployment? or that a beans.xml is not missing?

Comment: I have another producer that works (a simpler one with no type/enum) so I guess the DI works. About LoginProvider1Impl not part of the deployment, what do you mean? How would it be possible that the class is not deployed? All the classes are in the same package except for the helper (but same project).

Comment: you should open your logging for weld at the DEBUG level (org.jboss.weld DEBUG) and look for LoginProvider1Impl bean on discovery phase to see if it's listed and there are no problems with it.

Comment: Actually after re-reading your first comment I thought about bean instantiation and I added @ApplicationScoped to my 2 LoginProvider implementations and it seems like it works... I was wrong to expect the factory to create them, I guess I got confused with my other producer that really creates beans (instead of using Instance and InjectionPoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the annotation `@ApplicationScoped` to LoginProvider1Impl and LoginProvider2Impl.
Another way to make it work is to modify the factory method:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoginProviderFactory {

    @Produces
    @LoginProviderProducer
    public LoginProvider createLoginProvider(@Any Instance<LoginProvider> instance, InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Annotated annotated = injectionPoint.getAnnotated();
        LoginProviderType loginProviderTypeAnnotation = annotated.getAnnotation(LoginProviderType.class);
        Class<? extends LoginProvider> loginProviderType = loginProviderTypeAnnotation.value().getLoginProviderType();
        //return instance.select(loginProviderType).get();
        if (loginProviderType == LoginProvider1Impl.class) {
            return new LoginProvider1Impl();
        } else if (loginProviderType == LoginProvider2Impl.class) {
            return new LoginProvider2Impl();
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```