# CDI as a factory?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have this endpoint on my JAX-RS Java EE application:

```
public class SearchEndpoint implements ISearchEndpoint 
{

    @Inject protected SearchService searchService;

    @Override
    public Response search()
    {
        return Response.ok().entity(this.searchService.search()).build();
    }

}
```

In `searchService's search` method:

```
public class SearchService {

    @Inject private QueryVisitor visitor;

    public List<?> search() {
        for (Expression<?> group : groups)
            group.accept(this.visitor);
    }
}
```

And then in `QueryVisitor`,

```
@Override
public ESEntityPathPointer<?> visit(Expression<?> expr, ESEntityPathPointer<?> context) {
    switch ((EntityType)expr.getMetadata().getElement())
    {
        case digitalInput:
            if (context == null)
                context = new DigitalInputESEntityPathPointer();
            break;
        case followUpActivity:
            if (context == null)
                context = new FollowUpActivityESEntityPathPointer();
            break;
        case ...;
    }
    return context;
}
```

So, CDI injects a `SearchService` on my JAX-RS endpoint implementation, then CDI injects a `QueryVisitor` in previously injected `SearchService`.

So, As you're able to guess basicly `QueryVisitor.visit` acts as a factory. According to a `EntityType` enum value it creates an `ESEntityPathPointer<?>` object or another.

I'd like these objects are created using CDI.
I've read a bit about it, nevertheless I'm not quite able to figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
SomeBean bean = CDI.current().select(SomeBean.class).get();
```

Using qualifiers? Try the following:

```java
SomeBean bean = CDI.current().select(SomeBean, 
                                     new AnnotationLiteral<Qualifier1>(){}, 
                                     new AnnotationLiteral<Qualifier2>(){}).get();
```

Comment: It tells me: WELD-001308:   Unable to resolve any beans for Type: class DigitalInputESEntityPathPointer; Qualifiers: []

Comment: @Jordi You might get some insights from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31812173/1426227). BTW, do you have any qualifiers in your `DigitalInputESEntityPathPointer` class?

Comment: Yes. I've removed them and now it works. Could you get me a short briefing?

Comment: @Jordi You can keep the qualifiers. Try `CDI.current().select(DigitalInputESEntityPathPointer.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Qualifier1>(){}, new AnnotationLiteral<Qualifier2>(){}).get();`.